Why is there no established prayer for having (or raising) children?
Throughout Tanakh, we find that biblical heroes have specifically prayed to God for having children (such as Yitzhak and Hannah), and it seems like having children is generally considered a valid, desirable "good thing" by the Torah.[citation not needed]
Yet, unless I missed it, there doesn't seem to be any specific reference to such a request in the liturgy established by the Sages - no prayer for having children, raising children, or anything of the sort. Does anyone address why this is, or interpret any particular prayer as referring to such a request?
Note that I am specifically asking about rabbinically established prayers; anything composed after the 6th century does not count.
(As a sidepoint, there is a talmudic passage, Moed Kattan 28a, where Rava states that "children, lifespan, and sustenance depend upon mazal/fate [as opposed to a person's worthiness]". Especially in context, it is not obvious to me whether this would be an argument for or against praying for such things, but R. Bahyei to Devarim 31:14 at least understands this passage as emphasizing the importance of praying for children along with praying for one's health and livelihood, which strengthens my question)

Birkas Hatorah says may our offspring learn Torah...

Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16761/759

@DoubleAA I think that question is about praying for children's success, while this one is about having children

@Shalom that's true but it's not a request for children, it's just a reference to them

How old is כשם שנכנס לברית כן יכנס לתורה לחופה ולמעשים טובים?

We have a similar question on here somewhere and the answer given was that 'barech aleinu' is deemed to cover having children

Do יקום פרקן and והערב נא count?

@shmosel y'kum purkan would count, but it is Geonic (according to the Rokeach; I believe the earliest source is Mahzor Vitri). Basically, the question is - especially according to R. Bahyei above - that it seems like requests for children are central to the Torah's conception of what prayer is for, so why no formal establishment of such a thing in the Amidah?

Maybe it's because it doesn't apply equally to everyone.  Avraham aside, most 100-year-olds are not going to daven to have more children.  The established prayers are typically fixed for everyone.
Maybe there would be something in a piyut or other non-fixed prayer (which is basically where these kinds of prayers are now, just the ones we're familiar with are written more recently than you're looking for).

So what? But 100 y.o. can daven so that other Jews can have more children. A prayer on behalf of others has more strength.

Having children is a Mitzvah. There is no prayer to fulfil Mitzvot, i.e. there is no prayer for a Lulav. One must marry a woman who can have children, and even divorce his current wife if she cannot have children (Ktubot 77a). If he cannot have children, we never pray for a miracle.
Regarding raising children, there is an established prayer/bracha in the morning brachot, V'haarev na, we pray that our children and descendants should all know and follow Hashem and study Torah. (I also feel that it is alluded to in the blessing for Parnassah. They are bunched together in Dvarim 7:13 and the Gemara quoted. The Ben Ish Hai writes that the blessing of wealth is dependent on children (Od Yosef Hai, Breshit 25:21). The blessing is for wealth but is framed as a blessing on time, eg let what I have already done, planted/children end off well (this works out better with the wording of the Edot Hamizrah version of the bracha).)

We pray to bring korbanos all the time

Not established like the amida. The amida has the return of Kingdom to David which was lacking the whole second bet hamikdash. That's communal. In mussaf we do pray to bring the korban but I assume that was added after the destruction of the second temple. Also not as it's own bracha but as an addendum to the established one and that is also a communal korban

והשב את העבודה לדביר ביתך every single amidah.  Yes, of course it was only added when we weren't already bringing them, but that's the whole point.

That's referring to the aron ודביר בתוך הבית מפנימה הכין לתתן שם את ארון ברית ה' which was also missing second temple
